# If no threads are blocking a signal, and one thread is in `sigwait()`, is there any guarantee that the blocked thread will receive the next signal?

Tags: c++, multithreading, pthreads, signals

Suppose I have a multithreaded application that is not blocking any signals, and one thread calls `sigwait()` with a mask for `SIGTERM`. If the **process** receives a `SIGTERM` externally, are either of the following guaranteed?

1. The thread blocked on `sigwait()` will receive it.
2. The above thread is the **only** thread that will receive it.

I checked the [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/sigwait), but it does not address either of these questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At least for Linux: None of the two possiblities is guaranteed, as:

From [`man 7 signal`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/wait.2.html):

> The signal disposition is a per-process attribute: in a multithreaded application, the disposition of a particular signal is the same for all threads.

So as more than one thread does not block `SIGINT` those may received it.